# In Power Query (M), is there a way to force Text.Combine or Table.CombineColumns to return null when combining two nulls?

Tags: powerquery, m

I want to combine two columns, say Column1 and Column2 of type any. I think I have three options:

1. Use Table.AddColumn / each Text.Combine
2. Use Table.CombineColumns
3. Use Table.AddColumn / each (a custom function to get the behavior I want)

These three approaches are illustrated in the code below.

As far as I can tell, the only way I can get the behavior I want is by using the custom function shown.

So, my question is:

> Is there a way to force either Text.Combine or Table.CombineColumns to
> return null when attempting to combine null with null?

```
let
    Source = #table(
        {"Column1","Column2"},
        {
            {"1",null},
            {null,"2"},
            {null,null}
        }
    ),

    //Merging with Text.Combine makes null and null into ""
    merge_using_text_combine = Table.AddColumn(
        Source,
        "MergeWithTextCombine",
        each Text.Combine({Column1,Column2},"")
    ),

    //Merging with Table.CombineColumns - but row three becomes "", not null
    merged = Table.CombineColumns(
        Source,
        {"Column1","Column2"},
        Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("",QuoteStyle.None),
        "MergeWithTableCombineColumns"
        ),

    //function where null & null = null
    custom_combine = (columnX as any,columnY as any,optional sep as nullable text) => 
                        if 
                            columnX is null and columnY is null 
                        then 
                            null 
                        else 
                            Text.Combine(
                                {columnX,columnY},
                                if sep = null then "" else sep
                            ),
    
    //Combine using a custom function
    merge_using_custom_function = Table.AddColumn(
        Source,
        "UsingCustomFunction",
        each custom_combine([Column1],[Column2])
    )
    //,

    //blah = Text.Combine({null,null}), //produces text
    //blurp = null & null, //produces null, but so does 1 & null and so does null & 2
    //blahblah = Value.Is(blah,Text.Type) //TRUE
in
    merge_using_custom_function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but I first tested [Column1] and [Column2] equal to null before combining them. Note that I added a new line {"1","2"} to test it as well:

```
let
    Source = #table(
        {"Column1","Column2"},
        {
            {"1",null},
            {null,"2"},
            {"1","2"},
            {null,null}
        }
    ),
    merge_using_text_combine_ListAllTrue = Table.AddColumn(Source, "MergeWithTextCombine", each if List.AllTrue({[Column1]=null,[Column2]=null}) then null  else Text.Combine({[Column1],[Column2]},""))
in
    merge_using_text_combine_ListAllTrue
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I think that's similar to what I had concluded. I was wondering whether there was some shorthand to force this behavior in the comparer.

Comment: OK. That way, at least, there's no need to stop and manually enter data into the processing flow.